# cgal python exception

Tags: python, exception, cgal

```
from CGAL.Kernel import *
```

raises an exception as follows:

```
File "C:/Python26/Lib/site-packages/cgal\CGAL\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Kernel import *
ImportError: No module named Kernel
```

What could the reasons be? thanks

Comment: Well the most obvious reason is that there's no module named Kernel...

Comment: yes, but how to make it right

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently using the obsolete CGAL Python bindings.  I can only suggest to switch to the new ones, see : http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/